# SQL syntax error: Multi-part identifier could not be bound for ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server

Need to solve this

This is for a REST API and i need count on each row so that i can use it for Pagination purposes.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownum,
               *
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       ROW_NUMBER()
                         OVER (
                           ORDER BY sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownuminner
                FROM   (SELECT *
                        FROM   (SELECT sc.legacy_party_id,
                                       sc.practice,
                                       sr.risk_level
                                FROM   dbo.supplier sc
                                INNER JOIN dbo.risk sr
                                  ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sr.LEGACY_PARTY_ID)AS z) AS a)AS c
        WHERE  rownuminner <= ?)c
WHERE  rownum > ?;
```

Need elements of a table with row_number for each row but getting this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
> The multi-part identifier "sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
> The multi-part identifier "sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID" could not be bound.

Comment: `LEGACY_PARTY_ID` has the qualifier `sc`, but there are no objects aliased as `sc` in that query.

Comment: You never define a table named `sc`.

Comment: I also recommend against the reuse of aliases. But `FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MIP.SUPPLIER_INFO) AS z ) AS z )` could simply be written as `FROM MIP.SUPPLIER_INFO AS z` Why so many parenthesis?

Comment: Also, you have `WHERE rownum > 0`, however, `rownum` will never have a value <= 0. `ROW_NUMBER()` returns a **positive** value of 1 or more.

Comment: @Larnu  I also had that same thought, why make it more complicated?  What are we missing here?

Comment: I simplified the inner query. I have a table alias named sc.

Comment: rownum>? would be the query.The ? is replaced with input for each page for pagination. so that it creates sets for each page. the rownuminner and rownum creates sets

Comment: No, you do not have `sc` please update to post an accurate example so that we may better assist you here as your "simplification" seems to be obfuscation instead here.  We DO appreciate your attempt to simplify but please update to provide some clarity for us here.

Comment: So, what you're saying here, is that the query you've provided isn't representative of the real query? We can't help you if we don't have the ***real*** query.

Comment: ok. updated the whole query

Comment: `sc` is only in scope inside the derived table. Outside the derived table you need to refer to the derived table alias not the original alias the column was sourced from. With the full query there is still no need for that level of nesting

Comment: you can't use same alias for more than 1 subquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to reference an object by an alias that is within a subquery. You need to reference it by the correct alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownum,
             *
      FROM (SELECT *,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownuminner
            FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM (SELECT sc.legacy_party_id,
                               si.supplier_name,
                               si.supplier_description,
                               sc.practice,
                               sc.category,
                               sc.subcategory,
                               sui.industry,
                               sr.risk_level
                        FROM mip.supplier_classification AS sc
                             INNER JOIN mip.supplier_info AS si ON si.legacy_party_id = sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
                             INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_INDUSTRY AS sui ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sui.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
                             INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_RISK AS sr ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sr.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS z ) AS a ) AS c
      WHERE rownuminner <= 10) AS c
WHERE rownum > 5;
```

This still seems over complicated though. Looking at it, it could likely be far more simply written as:

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT sc.legacy_party_id,
            si.supplier_name,
            si.supplier_description,
            sc.practice,
            sc.category,
            sc.subcategory,
            sui.industry,
            sr.risk_level,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sc.legacy_party_id) AS RN
     FROM mip.supplier_classification AS sc
          INNER JOIN mip.supplier_info AS si ON si.legacy_party_id = sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
          INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_INDUSTRY AS sui ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sui.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
          INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_RISK AS sr ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sr.LEGACY_PARTY_ID)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= ?
  AND RN > ?;
```

Comment: Second example is better IMHO here, so I think we agree there.

Comment: can you update your answer to remove sensitive data. Thanks

Comment: There isn't any in there @Ram .

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER (
                   ORDER BY c.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownum,
               *
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       ROW_NUMBER()
                         OVER (
                           ORDER BY c.LEGACY_PARTY_ID) AS rownuminner
                FROM   (SELECT *
                        FROM   (SELECT sc.legacy_party_id,
                                       si.supplier_name,
                                       si.supplier_description,
                                       sc.practice,
                                       sc.category,
                                       sc.subcategory,
                                       sui.industry,
                                       sr.risk_level
                                FROM   mip.supplier_classification sc
                                       INNER JOIN mip.supplier_info si
                                               ON si.legacy_party_id = sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
                                       INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_INDUSTRY sui
                                               ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sui.LEGACY_PARTY_ID
                                       INNER JOIN mip.SUPPLIER_RISK sr
                                               ON sc.LEGACY_PARTY_ID = sr.LEGACY_PARTY_ID)AS z) AS a)AS c
        WHERE  rownuminner <= ?)c
WHERE  rownum > ?;
```

You have defined c alias for outer queries and using sc so it was giving error